# Sorting array of letters in alphabetical order

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

The idea is to scan an array of letters and sort them in alphabetical order

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    char letters[1000000];
    int i = 0, num_letters = 0, temp;
    scanf("%s", letters);

    while(letters[i] != '\0'){
        num_letters++;
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while(count < num_letters){
        while(i < num_letters - 1){
            if(letters[i] > letters[i+1]){
                temp = letters[i + 1];
                letters[i+1] = letters[i];
                letters[i] = temp;
            }
            i++;
        }
        count++;
    }
    printf("%s", letters);
    return 0;
}
```

The code is not working and I don't know why
for example, the string 'adsadf' prints back 'adadfs' instead of 'aaddfs'

Comment: Define 'not working'

Comment: As mentioned Paul Ogilvie your bubble sort inner index is not reset properly.

Comment: You shouldn't allocate such huge arrays on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

You must reset `i` before the inner-loop starts, so:

```
i = 0;
int count = 0;
while(count < num_letters){
    while(i < num_letters - 1){
```

should be

```
int count = 0;
while(count < num_letters){
    i = 0;
    while(i < num_letters - 1){
```

Note: learn to use a debugger and how to step through the code. You would have seen then that `i` was not the right value in the second iteration of the outer while loop.